# Maintaining Forked Repo Through Releases

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out what the best workflow would be for our case. We have a set of changes that we need to apply to the upstream project to adapt it to our environment that we don't want to upstream. However we do want to keep updated with the latest version from the upstream repo.

To start we have created a fork, and our master is pointed at v1.0 release of the upstream. We make commits A,B,C on master as needed and push to our master. Now v2.0 of upstream is released and we want to sync with with it and rebase A,B,C on it. However, if we do this on master I think we will be re-writing history and we lose v1.0.

We want our master to always have the latest upstream release with our set of changes. And the ability to easily check out an older release with our commits on it to re-build previous releases. How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to alter history, you could use `git merge --no-ff upstream/master` from master.

Comment: While it won't hurt anything, the `--no-ff` isn't really needed here.  It's kind of a "safety net" to make sure you get a new merge commit even if all of 'our' changes are already present on 'their' branch; but in this case we know they aren't.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thanks for the comment may I add it to my answer or do you want to suggest an edit? I think that it adds clarification.

Comment: Up to you; like I said, your answer isn't wrong as is - some people do just habitually use `--no-ff` regardless and it won't hurt anything in this situation.  I just wanted to provide the extra clarification.

Comment: Is there a strategy that allows us to use rebase instead of merge? I prefer the cleaner history but if not then we can just use merge.

Comment: @Otus If clean history is all that matters, you can use `--squash` which does not create merge information and add everything to the current index. AFAIK rebase always change history.